# pickle error assert id(obj) not in self.memo

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, dill

I am using [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) (advanced version of pickle) right now. I want to serialize my object, but I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in memoize(self, obj)
    242         if self.fast:
    243             return
--> 244         assert id(obj) not in self.memo
    245         memo_len = len(self.memo)
    246         self.write(self.put(memo_len))
```

Can someone tell me the possibility that made this error or how can I solved this?

Comment: Can you show us the code that throws the error?

Comment: At first glance then, `dill` is violating a `pickle` invariant; recursive structures should not lead to circular references being pickled *again*. `self.memo` tracks what has already been pickled before.

Comment: @enrico.bacis I am sorry the code is very very long and multiple files ... so I hardly show you ... but I am using Numpy, Scipy, Theano framework ...

Comment: @MartijnPieters so I should try to search the circular references that cause that problem ?

Comment: @psuedobot: perhaps; I don't know `dill` but the `id(obj) not in self.memo` assert is triggered if `id(obj)` has been seen before.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm the `dill` author.  It's just a big collection of using `copy_reg` for different objects, and I don't violate any `pickle` invariants… I do however do a few workarounds so all sorts of objects are added to the `memo` of `pickle` when you import `dill`.  There's no duplication in adding to memo, unless you do something weird like `import pickle`, then `copy_reg` some stuff, then `import dill` -- and that's probably even fine in many cases.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns: Right; I hadn't had time to look into `dill` internals at all. It sounds as if the OP should try to produce a minimal example that triggers the problem?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: absolutely.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am already tried to look my code and I didnt import pickle. I only import dill.

Comment: So? `dill` uses `pickle`; but follow Mike's advice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters now I already turn on the trace. And right before the assertion failed, it shown the pickle tried to serialized in line def __init___(self, ...)

Comment: @psuedobot It would help if you update your question to show the trace, or results of any of the `detect` methods you have tried as shown below in my post.  It's much harder to help w/o seeing what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Without you posting a reduced version of your code, it's hard to help.  However, `dill` has some builtin detection methods.  Look at `dill.detect`.

```
>>> # trace dill's pickling of objects, by printing out step by step trace 
>>> dill.detect.trace(True)
```

Or by object inspection.

```
>>> dill.detect.badobjects(yourfailingobject, depth=1)
```

There's also `dill.detect.badtypes` and so on.

Or you can trace down how objects relate to each other, with `dill.detect.parent`, `dill.detect.children`, `dill.detect.reference`, and so on.

Here's an example of using `dill` (plus `objgraph` for visualization) to track down circular references.  https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/58

There's also a big list of all that `dill` does not know how to serialize in `dill._objects` -- at least the first 15 sections of the python standard library, plus some others.

Comment: now I have tried dill.detect.trace(True). And the last row of the INFO before error pointing at the row where I coded def __init__(self, a, b, c) from the class's object that I want serialize.

Comment: @psuedobot: hard to tell what's going on from your above comment