# Python TypeError on Load Object using Dill

Tags: python, pickle, dill

Trying to render a large and (possibly very) unpicklable object to a file for later use.

No complaints on the `dill.dump(file)` side:

```
In [1]: import echonest.remix.audio as audio

In [2]: import dill

In [3]: audiofile = audio.LocalAudioFile("/Users/path/Track01.mp3")
en-ffmpeg -i "/Users/path/audio/Track01.mp3" -y -ac 2 -ar 44100 "/var/folders/X2/X2KGhecyG0aQhzRDohJqtU+++TI/-Tmp-/tmpWbonbH.wav"
Computed MD5 of file is b3820c166a014b7fb8abe15f42bbf26e
Probing for existing analysis

In [4]: with open('audio_object_dill.pkl', 'wb') as f:
   ...:     dill.dump(audiofile, f)
   ...:  

In [5]:
```

But trying to load the `.pkl` file:

```
In [1]: import dill

In [2]: with open('audio_object_dill.pkl', 'rb') as f:
   ...:     audio_object = dill.load(f)
   ...:
```

Returns following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-203b696a7d73> in <module>()
      1 with open('audio_object_dill.pkl', 'rb') as f:
----> 2     audio_object = dill.load(f)
      3 

/Users/mikekilmer/Envs/GLITCH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill-0.2.2.dev-py2.7.egg/dill/dill.pyc in load(file)
    185     pik = Unpickler(file)
    186     pik._main_module = _main_module
--> 187     obj = pik.load()
    188     if type(obj).__module__ == _main_module.__name__: # point obj class to main
    189         try: obj.__class__ == getattr(pik._main_module, type(obj).__name__)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load(self)
    856             while 1:
    857                 key = read(1)
--> 858                 dispatch[key](self)
    859         except _Stop, stopinst:
    860             return stopinst.value

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc in load_newobj(self)
   1081         args = self.stack.pop()
   1082         cls = self.stack[-1]
-> 1083         obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args)
   1084         self.stack[-1] = obj
   1085     dispatch[NEWOBJ] = load_newobj

TypeError: __new__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The AudioObject is much more complex (and large) than the `class object` the above calls are made on (from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/how-to-save-an-object-in-python/25119089)), and I'm unclear as to whether I need to send a second argument via `dill`, and if so, what that argument would be or how to tell if any approach to pickling is viable for this specific object.

Examining the object itself a bit:

```
In [4]: for k, v in vars(audiofile).items():
...:     print k, v
...:
```

returns:

```
is_local False
defer False
numChannels 2
verbose True
endindex 13627008
analysis <echonest.remix.audio.AudioAnalysis object at 0x103c61bd0>
filename /Users/mikekilmer/Envs/GLITCH/glitcher/audio/Track01.mp3
convertedfile /var/folders/X2/X2KGhecyG0aQhzRDohJqtU+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp9ADD_Z.wav
sampleRate 44100
data [[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

And `audiofile.analysis` seems to contain an attribute called `audiofile.analysis.source` which contains (or apparently points back to) `audiofile.analysis.source.analysis`

Comment: exploring the docs a bit more in depth - contained at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill

Comment: Am reading in https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html that "file must have two methods". Maybe the file I'm saving only has one method and that's the missing second argument that's breaking `cls.__new__(cls, *args)`

Comment: Is the `echonest` API something I could grab a hold of to try out if needed? Anyway, there are a few things that you can try to discover what's going on.  First, since it's a class, you can try to toggle the `byref` in `dill.dumps`, to toggle pickling the class "by reference".  If that doesn't work, try  turning on `dill.detect.trace(True)` to see internal checkpoints in the (de)serialization.  You can also look at methods in `dill.detect`, such as `badobjects` that can help diagnose what going on.  It looks like a mismatch in `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`, which would be weird.

Comment: It is, @MikeMcKerns.  http://echonest.com. There are two relevant modules available via http://developer.echonest.com/ and I shared the procedure at: http://www.mzoo.org/getting-the-python-echonest-remix-package-running. Are https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill, http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/pathos/wiki/dill and the pickle docs basically the extent of the reading material I should be looking at (in implementing the above recommendations)?

Comment: If using `with open('audio_object_dill.pkl', 'wb') as f:` byref would be set like this, `dill.dump(audiofile, f, byref=True)` with `False` being the default, right? `dill.load` results are the same. Entered `dill.detect.trace(True)` prior to `dill.dump` call results: http://pastebin.com/V0fA7aVJ. Lastly, `dill.detect.badobjects(audiofile)` returns `<echonest.remix.audio.LocalAudioFile at 0x103ebc710>`. Hmph.

Comment: First of all, wow is this a cool package. Digging around a bit, `dill.detect.children(audiofile, echonest.remix.audio.LocalAudioFile)` yields name 'echonest' is not defined - actually simply had to call it with the variable module was imported with: `dill.detect.children(audiofile, audio.LocalAudioFile)`, which yields our old friend `[<echonest.remix.audio.LocalAudioFile at 0x103ebc710>]`

Comment: Wait! Apparently the API has a built-in method: http://echonest.github.io/remix/apidocs/echonest.remix.audio-pysrc.html#LocalAudioFile.save

Comment: Geez that's a horrendous `trace` you have in the pastebin. Yes, that's all the reading material on `dill`, unfortunately.  By the way, you should try `badobjects(audiofile, depth=1)` -- that allows you to dig into each object, even ones that fail.  Also check out this as an example of what dill detection can do.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082241/how-to-get-a-python-functions-dependencies-for-pickling

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241139/pickle-error-assert-idobj-not-in-self-memo

Comment: Definitely had played with badobjects(audiofile, depth=1), but it hangs giving `f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self` in pickle's `save` method.

Comment: So did, the built-in "save" work from the API?  It looked like that may be what they expect you use (instead of `dump`, directly), and that might be why it seems like `load` expects something different.

Comment: Yes. Built-in save works and re-loads beautifully using Dill.

Comment: then you should answer your own question(s), as others might run into the same thing.

Comment: or I'll answer it.  someone should, so people don't need to dig into the comments.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I will answer it an look forward to having the opportunity to. Probably tomorrow and thank you for the reminder. Have been thinking about. I think i might even have the S.O. cred to add echonest as a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the answer lay within the module itself.

The `LocalAudioFile` class provides (and each of it's instances can therefor utilize) it's own `save` method, called via `LocalAudioFile.save` or more likely `the_audio_object_instance.save`.

In the case of an `.mp3` file, the `LocalAudioFile` instance consists of a pointer to a temporary `.wav` file which is the decompressed version of the `.mp3`, along with a whole bunch of analysis data which is returned from the initial audiofile, after it's been interfaced with the (internet-based) `Echonest API`.

[LocalAudioFile.save](http://echonest.github.io/remix/apidocs/echonest.remix.audio-pysrc.html#LocalAudioFile.save) calls `shutil.copyfile(path_to_wave, wav_path)` to save the `.wav` file with same name and path as original file linked to audio object and returns an error if the file already exists. It calls `pickle.dump(self, f)` to save the analysis data to a file also in the directory the initial audio object file was called from.

The `LocalAudioFile` object can be reintroduced simply via `pickle.load()`.

Here's an `iPython` session in which I used the `dill`, which is a very useful wrapper or interface that offers most of the standard `pickle` methods plus a bunch more:

```
audiofile = audio.LocalAudioFile("/Users/mikekilmer/Envs/GLITCH/glitcher/audio/Track01.mp3")

In [1]: import echonest.remix.audio as audio

In [2]: import dill
# create the audio_file object
In [3]: audiofile = audio.LocalAudioFile("/Users/mikekilmer/Envs/GLITCH/glitcher/audio/Track01.mp3")
en-ffmpeg -i "/Users/path/audio/Track01.mp3" -y -ac 2 -ar 44100 "/var/folders/X2/X2KGhecyG0aQhzRDohJqtU+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp_3Ei0_.wav"
Computed MD5 of file is b3820c166a014b7fb8abe15f42bbf26e
Probing for existing analysis
#call the LocalAudioFile save method
In [4]: audiofile.save()
Saving analysis to local file /Users/path/audio/Track01.mp3.analysis.en
#confirm the object is valid by calling it's duration method
In [5]: audiofile.duration
Out[5]: 308.96
#delete the object - there's probably a "correct" way to do this
in [6]: audiofile = 0
#confirm it's no longer an audio_object
In [7]: audiofile.duration
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-04baaeda53a4> in <module>()
----> 1 audiofile2.duration

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'duration'


#open the pickled version (using dill)
In [8]: with open('/Users/path/audio/Track01.mp3.analysis.en') as f:
   ....:     audiofile = dill.load(f)
   ....:     
#confirm it's a valid LocalAudioFile object
In [8]: audiofile.duration
Out[8]: 308.96
```

[Echonest](http://echonest.com/) is a very robust API and the remix package provides a ton of functionality. There's a small list of relevant links assembled [here](http://www.mzoo.org/getting-the-python-echonest-remix-package-running/).

Comment: I keep facing with following error `maximum recursion depth exceeded` is it normal?